# Web development in VIM

Tags: vim

I'm considering starting to use gVim instead of Notepad++ for web development. But first I need to improve Vim a little bit.

First of all I can't open any of my files, because I don't see a built-in FTP client. It would be nice, some FTP on the sidebar with tree views, you know, I bet there is one.

I don't wanna get rid of Emmet (formerly zencoding), which was the best plugin for np++ making my life so much easier.

I wanna turn on syntax highlighting for php,html,css,js,bash,ruby. I'm not sure how to do that.

Vim is not really popular for web development I guess, so since I'm finding nothing in Google I would really appreciate comments from you guys who already use Vim for webdev, I mean, tell me how effective it is, what plugins you use, how you make it faster, et cetera.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should break up each feature you wanto into a separate question. Syntax highlight for all the languages you mention is built-in should be turned on via: `filetype on + filetype plugin on` + `syntax on`.

Comment: Emmet-vim: https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim

Comment: I didn't wanna spam so with so many questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Emmet](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim) is available for vim.
- You can open files via ftp with the built-in netrw plugin, see `:help netrw`.
- Add the following lines to `$HOME\_vimrc` to activate filetype detection and syntax highlighting:

  ```
  filetype plugin indent on
  syntax on
  ```
- Be ready for a lot of reading.